# Using a textbox to take in an integer value for use in Javascript function. Is there a simpler way?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

I'm currently making a simple calculator for use in an intro to Javascript lesson. I would like to know if there's a simpler way of taking the value from a HTML input textbox as an integer than having to use the Javascript parse() method?

HTML:

```
<input type = "Text" id="num1">
```

JS:

```
var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
```

Comment: `+document.getElementById("num1").value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force a string to be a 32-bit integer like this:

```
var num1 = ~~document.getElementById("num1").value;
```

You can, alternatively, accept a number with a possible fractional part with

```
var num1 = +document.getElementById("num1").value;
```

In both cases, you can check to see if the original string really did look like a number by using `isNaN()`:

```
if (isNaN(num1)) {
  // bad input
}
```

Comment: ha ha I answered the linked duplicate too. I have a one-track brain.